# Centering of binary matrix for OCR

Tags: javascript, matrix, binary, ocr, centering

I'm reading characters from an image into 20x20 chunks to perform optical character recognition (OCR) and am wondering how to implement the best way of centering the binary data matrix.

For example, the character `h` might be converted into the following **one-dimensional** array (spaces and newlines added for clarity):

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

As far as I know, there are two alternatives:

1. **Center of mass**

   ```
   var mass = 0,
       sum = {
         x: 0,
         y: 0
       };

   for(y = 0; y < size; y++) {
     for(x = 0; x < size; x++) {
       if(chunk[size * y + x]) {
         sum.x += x;
         sum.y += y;
         mass++;
       }
     }
   }

   // diff center of mass and center of matrix
   var diff = {
     x: Math.round((size / 2) - (sum.x / mass)),
     y: Math.round((size / 2) - (sum.y / mass))
   };

   // move 1's accordingly
   ```

   Question is how to handle if this type of centering causes any of the 1's to be placed outside of the chunk and therefore corrupting the data?
2. **Bounding box**

   Calculate center of `min(x, y)` and `max(x, y)` and diff with center of matrix.

Which of these would yield the best (most consistent) results if the input characters are randomly distorted (slightly) in both dimensions?

The resulting chunk is used in training a multi-layer perceptron (MLP) neural network, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the bounding box method:

```
var min = {
  x: size,
  y: size
};
var max = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

for(y = 0; y < size; y++) {
  for(x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    if(chunk[size * y + x]) {
      if(min.x > x)
        min.x = x;

      if(min.y > y)
        min.y = y;

      if(max.x < x)
        max.x = x;

      if(max.y < y)
        max.y = y;
    }
  }
}

var diff = {
  x: Math.floor((size / 2) - (min.x + (max.x - min.x) / 2)),
  y: Math.floor((size / 2) - (min.y + (max.y - min.y) / 2))
};

// move 1's accordingly
```